# PIC16F1459 with DTMF chip phone dialer Loop issue (written in C)

Tags: c, pic, microprocessors, dtmf

I am currently working on an assignment that will dial a phone number when pressing a button on the board.  Currently I have the phone dialing the numbers I chose, however they are dialing one after another instead of when the button is pressed down.  Is there some real basic thing I am missing in my loop?

```
/* 
 * File:   assignment5.c
 *
 */
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF // Internal/External Switchover Mode (Internal/External Switchover Mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)
// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = ALL // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (000h to 1FFFh write protected, no addresses may be modified by PMCON control)
#pragma config CPUDIV = CLKDIV6 // CPU System Clock Selection Bit (CPU system clock divided by 6)
#pragma config USBLSCLK = 48MHz // USB Low SPeed Clock Selection bit (System clock expects 48 MHz, FS/LS USB CLKENs divide-by is set to 8.)
#pragma config PLLMULT = 3x // PLL Multipler Selection Bit (3x Output Frequency Selected)
#pragma config PLLEN = DISABLED // PLL Enable Bit (3x or 4x PLL Disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */


void pulse(void){
                  RC6 = 0;  //drop clock
                  __delay_us(5);
                  RC6 = 1;
                  __delay_us(5);
}

void tone_0(){
      char i;

      RC7 =0;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 =1;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 =1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
     // RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
         // pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_1(){
      char i;

      RC7 =1;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
     // RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_2(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 0;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_3(){
      char i;

      RC7 =1;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 =1;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
         // pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_4(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 0;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 =0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
     // RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_5(){
      char i;

      RC7 =1;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
         // pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_6(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 0;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_7(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 1;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_8(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 0;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
void tone_9(){
      char i;

      RC7 = 1;  //data low
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 1;
      pulse();
      RC7 = 0;
      pulse();
      __delay_ms(195);
      //RC7 = 1;
      //for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
          //pulse();
      //__delay_ms(195);
}
char dial(char i)
{
    if(i == 0)
        {
            tone_6();
    }
    if(i == 1)
        {
            tone_7();
    }
    if(i == 2)
        {
            tone_3();
    }
    if(i == 3)
        {
            tone_3();
    }
    if(i == 4)
        {
            tone_8();
    }
    if(i == 5)
        {
            tone_6();
    }
    if(i == 6)
        {
            tone_9();
    }
    i++;
    if(i > 6)
        i = 0;
    return i;


}
 void main(){
                  char i = 0;
                  char buttontoggle = 0;
                  char count = 0;
                                    __delay_ms(190);

                                    OSCCON =0b00110100;
                                    TRISC = 0;
                                    ANSELC = 0;
                                    TRISA = 0b11111111;
                                    WPUB6 = 1;

                                    PORTC = 0b10000100;  //clock high, data high, CE high
                                    __delay_ms(10);
                                     RC2 = 0;  //turn it on.
                                    __delay_ms(10);
             while(1)
             {

        if(RB6 == 0 )
                {
                    buttontoggle = 0;
        }
        if(RB6 == 1)
                {
                    buttontoggle = 1;
        }
                if( buttontoggle == 1)
                {
                    count = dial(count);
                }

         }

/*while (1){

                                    RC2 = 0;  //turn it on.
                                    __delay_ms(50);
                                    RC7 =1;  //data low
                                    pulse();
                                    RC7 =0;
                                    pulse();
                                    RC7 =0;
                                    pulse();
                                    RC7 =1;
                                    pulse();
                                    RC7 = 0;
                                    pulse();
                                    __delay_ms(195);
                                    RC7 = 1;
                                    for (i = 0;i<5;i++)       pulse();
                                    __delay_ms(195);
                                    RC2 =1;
        }*/
}
```

Comment: I'm removing "Compiler-Construction" as a tag.  I can't see how this fits.

Comment: Does the dialing stop when the button is pressed?

Comment: I don't see any software debouncing on that RB6 button, is it debounced by hardware instead?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to look at the hardware. You have not set up port B, but we'll assume it is an input. Is the value of RB6 ever going low?

If RB6 is set properly, this code will dial your number continuously as long as the button is pressed (i.e. there is no escape).

Your dial routine (which is begging for a case statement!) is also self-modifying the parameter i, as well as returning it, and then you assign the return value to the calling parameter (count). That's somewhat convoluted and may cause strange behaviour.